# Schema.org markup taking too long to index

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, rich-snippets, schema.org

I run a doctor discovery platform. It has individual profiles for each doctor (over 700 profiles). I've added schema markup to the profiles.

It's been more than 5 months and still not all the profiles have schema markup being shown in SERP. I can see in the Google search console that the graph is slowing going up. So more and more schema markup is getting indexed. But it's too slow!

Is that normal? Does it take that long? If yes, is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Schema can take several months to appear in the search results, once its been first discovered. If you have 700 profiles then you need to do the math and see if Google has discovered them all in Web Master Tools, if it hasn't then it will take much longer for Google to display those in the results.

*Thin content is considered less important and therefore given less priority*

Profile pages are generally considered low-quality to Google and other search engines unless they have unique content, are freshened once in a while and have around 200-300 words on the page. If the they are low quality then it can take months to have Google revisit those pages to discover the markup, Google may never return unless you force it hands. While Google has an insane amount of resources its sadly not unlimited, sites are prioritised on importance and quality.

*Schema markup is sometimes is disabled in search results*

It's **NOT UNCOMMON** for Google not to be display SCHEMA in all serps, its pretty common and just because you have the markup doesn't mean Google will display it. Google can select pages it believes is more important and others, and enable SCHEMA in the results, lower quality pages it may not, also page content and niche plays a huge role in what gets returned or not.

Schema is automated and the only way to get it to appear quicker is to have those pages discovered, if they have been the its out of your hands. They will show in time and if they don't then its because Google has decided not to return SCHEMA in the search on that practical page which could be for many unknown reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I have done schema for all my products pages almost like a month before and checking every week if it has been indexed.Yes, its true that adding schema does not mean that it will reflect its all depends on the traffic and CTR of the page on basis that Google will have call to reflect it or not.As an example if your website  have like 1000 pages and all are updated with schema code but out of that let's say 21 are highly traffic pages so schema might be reflecting on all or some of them depends on google algorithm which only Googles know.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer already selected, but there were somethings not mentioned that should be mentioned.  First schema.org tagging is one of two ways to actually get this information crawled and indexed by google.  Google Webmaster tools allows data highlighting as an alternative which does not require that you have schema tags on your entire website. Google can learn based on your posts and articles how to read the data on your website, you just manually select a sample of data for google to learn from.

Two You can force crawls in Google to help speed up the process of indexing for your website. Many users forget to use many of the advanced features of Google Webmaster tools. Which are very beneficial for many websites, especially if you are trying to index pages quickly.  If you would like individual pages that have not been indexed yet to be force crawled try using the fetch as google tool to help get that page indexed faster.